# How do I return status 500 and stop running the script for that route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If an error occurs in a custom function, I would like to stop the script from running and return the response with a 500 error.

However my script is running the error, and later continuing the script.

**./helpers.js**

```js
const requiredEnv = (vars, callback) => {
  const unsetEnv = vars.filter((varName) => !(typeof process.env[varName] !== 'undefined'));
  let error;
  if (unsetEnv.length > 0) {
    error = "Required ENV variables are not set: [" + unsetEnv.join(', ') + "]";
  }
  callback(error);
}

module.exports = { requiredEnv };
```

**./route.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const requiredEnv = require('./requiredEnv');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  requiredEnv(['MY_VAR'], (error) => {
    console.log('this is an error shown in the console');
    res.status(500).send({ error });
    // should stop this script here...
  });

  // somehow it continues here, even though the previous callback function is returning an error
  console.log('this is continued');

  res.status(200).send({ message: 'Message sent' });

});
module.exports = router;
```

I've tried `next()` but that did not work.

---

## update

I almost have it working. (thanks @oooyaya & @ayush)

```
const middlewareFoo = function(_, res, next) {
  requiredEnv(['MY_VAR'], function (error) {
    if (error) {
      // ✓ it stops when MY_VAR is not present
      return res.status(500).send({ error });
    } else {
      // ✗ when MY_VAR is defined, it does not continue...
      console.log('continue if no error...');
      next()
    }
  });
}

router.use(middlewareFoo);

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
// ... left out for brevity
```

But if there's no error it's not working. Similar issue I guess.

Comment: Just throw an Error and it stops running and `express` automatically sends 500 status to a user. Of course you should be careful with an async code.

Comment: also note that you don't need `else{}` if your `if()` has a return.  It helps to avoid some of the super deep nesting Node is prone to.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this will likely get you closer.  The problem is that you're running asyncy code and so the `res.send(200)` happens before the callback to the `requiredEnv()` callback.  They need to live within the same callback and you can check if there was an error or not.  If so, `res.status(500)`.  If not, `res.status(200)`.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  requiredEnv(['MY_VAR'], (error) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log('this is an error shown in the console');
        res.status(500).send({ error });
        // should stop this script here...
        return;
    }

    console.log('this is continued');
  
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Message sent' });
  });


});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: As a suggestion, maybe extract the `requiredEnv` call to a midddleware

Comment: @oooyaya I see how using the same callback works. But I can imagine that it becomes a callback hell within a callback (etc.) quickly. Is my code async even though I'm not using a promise or await?

Comment: @AyushGupta  I've update the answer using middleware (nice suggestion!). But it seems I have the same problem there.

Comment: @Remi looking at your implementation of `requiredEnv`, it seems you don't invoke the callback if there is no error.

Comment: @AyushGupta yes -- using callbacks gets you into callback hell.  this is a very common problem in Node.  There are strategies to avoid it but generally "error first callbacks" (callbacks where the first argument is any error which occurred or null if no errors) are an intentional design choice.

for similar reasons, i don't know this requiredEnv() method but I'm assuming that error is nullable if no error occurred.  If not, then the `if(error)` thing I put in isn't going to work.  The idea is "if theres an error, do this.  if not, do that".  I dont know how the library expresses that though.

Comment: @oooyaya Oh I'm talking about OPs implementation of `requiredEnv` in the question. If there is no error, the OP doesnt invoke the callback. The callback needs to be called in that case too, just with  a null error. Otherise, control doesn't go to the positive case.